# How to perform a proper loop

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to change a few addresses. However, I need the code to update them almost consistently. The code WORKS, BUT, when the checkbox is checked, it freezes and wont let me Unchecked it. (To stop changing the addresses)

Iv'e also tryed:

```
Loop While CheckBox1.CheckState = 1
```

But that does not help the issue.

Code:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.Click
    If IsProcessRunning("Notepad") = True Then
        Do
            Try
                WriteInteger("Notepad", &H49E6CC, 99)
                WriteInteger("Notepad", &H49E6D4, 99)
            Catch ex As Exception
            End Try
        Loop While True
    Else
        CheckBox1.CheckState = 0
        MessageBox.Show("Notepad Not Running!")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: How do you expect to fall out the loop?

Comment: By un-checking the CheckBox1.

Comment: But you have no test to let you fall out the loop. Rather do this with a pair of buttons, a timer and a class level variable.

Comment: Alright, Ill give that a shot

Comment: You wont be able to uncheck it cause your code wont respond as it is in infinite loop, even if you are able to un-check it where are you checking the condition that it is checked in in do while loop.

Comment: What ways can you get around that? @user64322

Comment: You run your whole loop and writing on the UI thread in an infinite loop. So you will not be able to use anything in UI, even not your checkbox. Make the writing stufff a background worker and cancel it when the checkbox is pressed.

Comment: @AlexB. Yeah... I noticed, It freezes up. However, how would I make the writing stuff a background worker? Example?

Comment: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx) has a decent example at the bottom

Comment: Yay, more game [Counter-Strike] hacks! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Problem Solved] Appreciate everyone help!

```
    Dim Timer1 As New Timer
Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged
    If CheckBox1.CheckState = 1 Then
        AddHandler Timer1.Tick, AddressOf Timer1_Tick
        Timer1.Interval = 500
        Timer1.Start()

    Else
        RemoveHandler Timer1.Tick, AddressOf Timer1_Tick
        Timer1.Stop()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    WriteInteger("Notepad", &H49E6D4, 99)
    WriteInteger("Notepad", &H49E6CC, 99)
End Sub
```

Comment: Slight note, I would stop the timer then remove the handler. Not sure if it has any impact but this is how I'd feel it should logically work.

Answer (score 1):

The application becomes unresponsive when you click on the checkbox because you have written an infinite loop in the event handler. The main thread of the application handles the execution of the UI events.

You need to create a separated mechanism that is going to continuously executes your logic, such as a [BackgroundWorker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx) or using [a separated thread](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread(v=vs.110).aspx).

Thus, the event handler of the check box only enables/disables the `BackgroundWorker` or the separated `Thread`.